# Is a POST controller suitable in a php mvc?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, class

I am creating a custom MVC style framework from scratch and am at the point where I need to implement the code to control what happens on `POST`.

At the moment I have a main index.php which acts as a controller and passes data to other controllers such as:

profilecontroller.class.php
forumcontroller.class.php

At the moment I see two options as to where the POST controllers can go ..

**First Approach**

Firstly for site wide posts such as **login** that can occur on any page I would use something like this in the very first index.php to redirect all POST to a specific POST controller that then sends the data to a model to be processed:

```
if($_POST)
    //post controller, works on specific form id's
```

**Alternate Approach**

The other option I see would be to build the `POST` identifier into the model construction sections but I don't think this would be very manageable/wise as they'd always be checked and resulting in more loaded code?

Are there any good/simple examples out there?

I'm creating my mvc to be as light as possible so that's my reason for going from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a RESTful setup, you would normally have a controller for an object, say `news`, and then actions such as `add`, `edit`, `delete` etc.

Within your actions, you should then assert what HTTP method should be used to access the method, if one should be. For example:

```
<?php
class NewsController extends AbstractController {
    public function save() {
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
            header('HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed');
            die('Please use POST.');
        }
        // carry on knowing we're working with a POST request
    }
}
```

Creating a separate controller for POST requests would, as you say, quickly becoming unruly and unmanageable.

If you're looking for a way of handling requests for different HTTP methods within different controller actions, then maybe check out [ToroPHP](https://github.com/anandkunal/ToroPHP). It's a lightweight (single file) router, where you map a request to a class that's referred to as a handler, and then that handler has methods for different HTTP methods. A quick example:

```
<?php

require 'lib/torophp/toro.php';
require 'classes/handlers/HomeHandler.php';

$toro = new ToroApplication(array(
    array('/', 'HomeHandler')
));
$toro->serve();
```

And then your `HomeHandler` would look as follows:

```
<?php
class HomeHandler {
    public function get() {
        echo 'Hello, world!';
    }
    public function post() {
        echo 'Try performing a GET request for the home page, buddy.';
    }
    // and so on...
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is my default Controller :

```
<?php
Class Controller_Home{
    public $Registery = null;

    final public function __construct($Registery){ $this->Registery = $Registery; }

    final public function Init($Method=null){
        # Quelle action on fait ?
        if($Method){
            $Split = explode('_', $Method);

            $MethodName = 'Action';
            foreach($Split as $Splitted){
                $MethodName.= '_'.ucfirst($Splitted);
            }

            if(method_exists($this, $MethodName)){
                $this->$MethodName();
            } else {
                echo '404';
                die;
            }
        } else {
            $this->Action_Default();
        }
    }

    final public function Action_Default(){
        $this->Registery->Import('Library.Account');

        var_dump($this->Registery->Account);
        echo 'Default Home';
    }
}
```

As you can see, once you are in Action_Default, you can do whatever you want based on $_GET, $_POST, whatever you want ...

So with this code :

website.com/home/bob/ will use function `Action_Bob` inside the controller `Home` (`Home::Action_Bob`) ... if you see $_POST just put inside `Action_Bob` this

```
public function Action_Bob(){
    if($_POST){
        $this->Action_Bob_Post();
    }
    // continue
}
```